# What's the Microsoft unit-testing alternative to the InlineData or TestCase attributes?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, vs-unit-testing-framework

Unit test frameworks other than Microsoft have options to add input parameters and expected results using attributes.

For example,

NUnit has

```
[TestCase(12,4,3)]
```

and xUnit has

```
[InlineData(5, 1, 3, 9)]
```

What's the Microsoft way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to add Nuget packages **MSTest.TestFramework** and **MSTest.TestAdapter** (*for discovery of tests*) and remove the reference of `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll` which is added by default. You are good to go to add input parameters:

```
[TestMethod]
[DataRow(10)]
[DataRow(20)]
[DataRow(30)]
public void TestMethod1(int inputValue)
{
    Assert.AreEqual(10, inputValue);
}
```