# One Unit Test with different Data

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, testing, intervals

(In VS and C#)

I want to run ONE Unit test for like 10 Times.
The Test is the same, but the Data should be different.
It should be like with "[DataRow(10)]", but then its just ten, but i want to Test FROM ZERO TO TEN.

For Example:

```
[TestMethod]
Public void TestIfNumbersAreEqual()
{
    Assert.AreEqual(1,1)
}
```

But i want to overdrive the Parameters from Zero to Ten.
So there should be like 11 Tests.

What is the matched Attribut or what do i need?

Hope you understand this Problem.
Could someone help me please, i cant get the right answer for this.

Thank you very much guys :)

(Im new in this Area, but in need this Solution very quick...)

Answer (score 0):

if you're using xUnit, use the Theory Attribute with InlineData

```
[Theory]
[InlineData("TeSt CaSe", "tEsT cAsE")]
[InlineData(null, null)]
[InlineData("", "")]
public void MyFunc(string first, string second)
{
     Assert.Equal(first, second);
}
```

Comment: then, check this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/46966786/11775586

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible with NUnit (a test framework, which can be found as a Nuget package). You example would look something like this:

```
[TestCase(1,1)]
[TestCase(2,2)]
[TestCase(3,3)]
public void TestOfNumbersAreEqual(int a, int b)
{
    Assert.AreEqual(a, b);
}
```

You can see more examples in the [documentation](https://nunit.org/docs/2.6/testCase.html).

For NUnit to work, you need to install the following Nuget packages in your test project:
[image]

Comment: Thank you, But i need a Range from 1 to 10.
I dont want to Write down 10 DataRow´s.
I just want a Range that i can establish.
I need it because i need this for other tests with over 1000 Test.
I want to run ONE ms unit test multiple TImes with data like from 1 to 1000. That means, that the Test should be run 1000 Times. The first time mit the number 1, the second with number 2...
Could you help?